# Why is this cron not working?

Tags: crontab, centos-6

I've made a script that backs some files up and puts them in a folder,

When I do

```
sudo /data/backups/scripts/nightlybackups.sh
```

It works, I just want to make it a cron job so that it runs every night

I have this line in /etc/crontab

```
30 23 * * * /bin/bash /data/backups/scripts/nightlybackups.sh
```

The script leaves a log file, indicating when it was called, and I can see that the cron never calls this script, am I doing something wrong?

This is a centos machine, here is the output of uname -a

```
Linux venus 2.6.32-279.1.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 10 13:47:21 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: There should be no need to call bash. Try adding `#!/bin/bash` in the first line of your file instead. Check the cron log for more information and enable e-mailing the execution output to you if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When adding entries to `/etc/crontab` you must include a username.

So something like

```
30 23 * * * root /bin/bash /data/backups/scripts/nightlybackups.sh
```

Past that you need to examine your scripts use of environment variables.  Cron has a very limited environment/PATH/etc.  Some of the variables you have set in your interactive shell probably won't be set the same when the script is run from cron.